# Are the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi accessible from gForth?

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi2, gforth

I am building a robot and want to use gForth to develop the software. I am unable to tell, after looking through the manual and searching on the web, whether or not the GPIO pins can be changed from within gForth running on a Raspberry PI 2. In Python there is the GPIO library that gets imported. But, I see no provision for that in gForth.

Has anyone had success in doing this from gForth?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but here's what I do. I access the port using the /sys/class/gpio/ file structure. It means using the EXPORT file, the DIRECTION file and the VALUE file. It works perfectly. 
Let me know if you need more info.